Segmentar una serie de valores
Estoy intentando segmentar una serie de valores dentro de un dataframe en función de una columna factor. el dataset de ejemplo sería como este:



rr_1
time_1
rr_2
time_2
resp_time_1
resp_time2




11
0.0
21
0.0
1
1


12
1.2
22
0.3
2
1


13
1.8
23
1.0
2
1


14
2.5
24
1.3
3
2


15
3.0
25
2.0
3
2


NA
NA
26
2.3
NA
3


NA
NA
27
3.0
NA
3



Quiero segmentar las series que contienen "rr" en función de la correspondiente columna "resp_time".

rr_1 con resp_time_1

rr_2 con resp_time_2


El resultado que quiero obtener sería el siguiente:



id
resp
lista_rr




1
1
11


1
2
12, 13


1
3
14, 15


2
1
21, 22, 23


2
2
24, 25


2
3
26, 27



Este es el código que he intentado para la parte de segmentación:

segmentar <- function(dataframe){
  col_rr <- grep("rr", names(dataframe))
  col_resp <- grep("resp", names(dataframe))
  lista_listas <- list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(col_rr)){
    for(j in seq_along(col_resp)){
      if(i == j){
        nombre <- paste(names(dataframe)[i], "RESP", sep = "_")
        lista_listas[[nombre]] <- split(dataframe[[i]], dataframe[[j]])
      }
    }
  }
  return(lista_listas)
}

Muchas gracias,

No es un código bonito, pero hace lo que necesitas:
datos %>% 
  select(rr_1, resp_time_1) %>% 
  na.omit %>% 
  mutate(lista_rr = toString(rr_1), .by = resp_time_1,
         id = 1) %>% 
  filter (! duplicated(lista_rr)) %>% 
  rename(resp = resp_time_1) %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  rbind(
    datos %>% 
      select(rr_2, resp_time2) %>% 
      na.omit %>% 
      mutate(lista_rr = toString(rr_2), .by = resp_time2,
             id = 2) %>% 
      filter (! duplicated(lista_rr)) %>% 
      rename(resp = resp_time2) %>% 
      select(-1)
  ) %>% 
  relocate(id, .before = resp)

  id resp   lista_rr
1  1    1         11
2  1    2     12, 13
3  1    3     14, 15
4  2    1 21, 22, 23
5  2    2     24, 25
6  2    3     26, 27

Los datos son los siguietes:
datos <- structure(list(rr_1 = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, NA, NA), time_1 = c(0, 
1.2, 1.8, 2.5, 3, NA, NA), rr_2 = 21:27, time_2 = c(0, 0.3, 1, 
1.3, 2, 2.3, 3), resp_time_1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA), 
    resp_time2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

Otra forma de hacerlo es evitando duplicar código e ir así:
library(tidyr)
lst <- datos %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("resp"), names_to = "id", values_to =  "resp") %>% 
  mutate(id = sub("\\D+", "", id)) %>% 
  select(id, resp, rr_1, rr_2) %>% 
  split(.$id) 


lapply(seq_len(length(lst)), \(i) { 
  tmp <- grep(i, names(lst[[i]]), value = TRUE)
  lst[[i]] %>% 
    mutate(lista_rr = toString(get(tmp)), .by = resp) %>% 
    filter (! duplicated(lista_rr)) %>% 
    select(id, resp, lista_rr) 
  } 
) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  na.omit

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  id     resp lista_rr  
  <chr> <int> <chr>     
1 1         1 11        
2 1         2 12, 13    
3 1         3 14, 15    
4 2         1 21, 22, 23
5 2         2 24, 25    
6 2         3 26, 27 


Esta es una solución clásica con R base usando la función de agregación aggregate() que te permitirá segmentar y por cada grupo aplicar una función, que en tu caso sería la concatenación de valores (entiendo)
data <- read.table(text =  "rr_1    time_1  rr_2    time_2  resp_time_1 resp_time2
11  0.0 21  0.0 1   1
12  1.2 22  0.3 2   1
13  1.8 23  1.0 2   1
14  2.5 24  1.3 3   2
15  3.0 25  2.0 3   2
NA  NA  26  2.3 NA  3
NA  NA  27  3.0 NA  3", header=TRUE)

s1 <- setNames(data[,c("rr_1", "resp_time_1")], 
           c("lista_rr", "resp"))

s2 <- setNames(data[,c("rr_2", "resp_time2")], 
               c("lista_rr", "resp"))

rbind(
  aggregate(lista_rr ~ resp, s1, c),
  aggregate(lista_rr ~ resp, s2, c)
)

  resp   lista_rr
1    1         11
2    2     12, 13
3    3     14, 15
4    1 21, 22, 23
5    2     24, 25
6    3     26, 27

Comentarios:

Necesitamos unificar previamente los nombres de las variables que usaremos
una vez unificados los nombres, con dos aggregates() hacemos las segmentación que buscas
lista_rr ~ resp en aggregate() es una notación fórmula que indica: "quiero agrupar por resp y voy a aplicar una función a resp
En este ejemplo, aplicamos en cada caso la función c() que simplemente crea un vector con los valores de `resp`` en cada segmento o grupo

Si usas tidverse puedes resolverlo de forma similar, la idea es la misma, unir los dos grupos de datos y agrupar:
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  select(resp=resp_time_1, lista_rr=rr_1) %>% 
  mutate(grupo=1) %>% 
  union (data %>% 
          select(resp=resp_time2, lista_rr=rr_2) %>% 
          mutate(grupo=2)
         ) %>% 
  group_by(grupo, resp) %>% 
  summarise(lista_rr=paste(lista_rr, collapse = ","), .groups="drop") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(resp)) %>% 
  select(resp, lista_rr)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
   resp lista_rr
  <int> <chr>   
1     1 11      
2     2 12,13   
3     3 14,15   
4     1 21,22,23
5     2 24,25   
6     3 26,27  


Aunque me gusta mucho tu solución con aggregate y tu propuesta usando dplyr, verifca que el resultado que obtenés no es igual al requerido en la pregunta.

gracias @JilberUrbina, corregido, finalmente era todo mas sencillo, ahi reedite la respuesta.
